# Set up NavigationController from Modal View and set layout in interface builder?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to set up a NavigationController from a Modal View, but I can't figure out how to set the layout options using interface builder.  Here's the code I'm using.

```
 //Create the view you want to present modally
 UIViewController *modalView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
 //Create a new navigation stack and use it as the new RootViewController for it
 UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]          
 initWithRootViewController:modalView];
 //Present the new navigation stack modally
 [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
 //Release
 [modalView release];
 [nav release];
```

Is there anyway to set the layout options of the navigationcontroller in interface builder?  I tried setting the color using

```
nav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:128 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
```

but that results in a bright red instead of the maroon color this RGB combination is supposed to result in.

It would be much easier for me if I could control the NavigationController options from interface builder, is this possible given this setup?

Comment: you can only set the tint color of the Navigation Bar in your main view in IB. If you want to change the tint between views you'll have to hardcode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating these views programmatically, there's nothing to set in interface builder. You can, however, programmatically set the tint color. Your problem is that the UIColor initializer takes floats between 1.0f and 0.0f for the intensity of the color. Your 128 is simply clamped to 1.0f, hence bright red. Try this instead:

```
nav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f blue:0 green:0 alpha:1.0f];
```

That should give you a color closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the tint color using the interface builder. You will have to hard code it, just like you had implied in your question.

You have two options.

1. Use the RGB values, with different values of `alpha` to get Maroon and then use it.
2. Create Maroon background `(using paint or photoshop)`, and set that as your `background view.`